# Why is this code working in testing but with a load event, it does not

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering why this code is working in a project for itself but as soon as i add a window.addEventListner("load") function it stops working.

Original working code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="click">Click</button>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    var count = 0;
    var timeout;
    function test() {
        console.log(count);
        count = count + 1;
        timeout = setTimeout("test()", 1000);
    }

    document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        test();
    }, false);
</script>
```

Modified Javascript code which gives me this error 'ReferenceError: test is not defined.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var count = 0;
        var timeout;
        function test() {
            console.log(count);
            count = count + 1;
            timeout = setTimeout("test()", 1000);
        }

        document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            test();
        }, false);
}
```

Comment: Seems missing `)` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally,i know what you mean ,try to run this on your console:

```
var site = "global";

function foo() {
    var site = "partial";
    setTimeout('alert(site);', 100);
}
foo();
```

ok,tell me ,what do you got ? partial or global?

sorry,it is 'global'!

that is because,string in the setTimeout(the first argument ) is executed in the global scope,so when the 'alert(site)' executing , it will find

```
var site = "global";
```

and will never find

```
var site = "partial";
```

because this site is in the function foo scope,in general,we can't visit variable defined in the function scope out of the function except closure.
in this case,we can not visit variable site defined in the foo in the global scope.
so,if you don't define site in the global ,you will get the error ,for example:

```
var s = "global";

function foo() {
    var site = "partial";
    setTimeout('alert(site);', 100);
}
foo();
```

what do you got ?

Uncaught ReferenceError: site is not defined

that is exactly why you got error after you add a window.addEventListner("load") function.Now,pay attention to the following codes ,especially comments.

```
<script>
// when you visit function test in the setTimeout,you visit it here!
// you didn't define another function test in the global,
//if you defined,it will execute this function test
 window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var count = 0;
        var timeout;

        function test() {
            console.log(count);
            count = count + 1;
            timeout = setTimeout("test()", 1000);
            // you can't visit function test in the global,because function test is defined in this anonymous function
        }

        document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            test();
        }, false);
});
</script>
```

keep going ,see this

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="click">Click</button>
</body>

</html>
<script>
function test() {
    console.log('in the global')
};
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var count = 0;
    var timeout;

    function test() {
        console.log(count);
        count = count + 1;
        timeout = setTimeout("test()", 1000);
    }

    document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        test();
    }, false);
});
</script>
```

what do you got ?

> 0
>
> in the global

so,i guess you understand now,we are going to talk about how to fix the problem,just remove the "" or '' and (),use the function name is fine.

```
timeout = setTimeout(test, 1000);
```

this will make it execute normally.actually,we do not use the following type,

```
timeout = setTimeout("test()", 1000);
```

due to historical reasons,you can stil see this kind of code ,but we don't suggest,and it will consume performance,that's all,hope you understand.

Comment: Thats exactly what i experinced and was conserned about thank you for taking the time to specify what were going on it made it very clear :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error, closing `)` is missing

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var count = 0;
  var timeout;

  function test() {
    console.log(count);
    count = count + 1;
    timeout = setTimeout(test, 1000); //observe this change as well.
  }

  document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    test();
  }, false);
}); //this final `)` was missing
```

**Demo**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var count = 0;
  var timeout;

  function test() {
    console.log(count);
    count = count + 1;
    timeout = setTimeout(test, 1000);
  }

  document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    test();
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<button id="click">Click</button>
```

**Note**

Following line in your code

```
timeout = setTimeout("test()", 1000);
```

causes

> "message": "Script error."

Hence has been changed to

```
timeout = setTimeout(test, 1000);
```

Comment: I will accept the answer, because it must be something else which is wrong in my original code. because in the original code everything is close properly, but for some reason it gives me the error i mentionen.

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 Did you check the update about usage of `setTimeout` in your code.